# Entire text is matched but not able to group in named groups

Tags: regex

I have following example text:

`my_app|key1=value1|user_id=testuser|ip_address=10.10.10.10`

I want to extract sub-fields from it in following way:

```
appName = my_app, 
[
    {key = key1, value = value1}, 
    {key = user_id, value = testuser}, 
    {key = ip_address, value = 10.10.10.10}
]
```

I have written following regex for doing this:

`(?<appName>\w+)\|(((?<key>\w+)?(?<equals>=)(?<value>[^\|]+))\|?)+`

It matches the entire text but is not able to group it correctly in named groups.

Tried testing it on https://regex101.com/

[image: regex tester]

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Rob  - just wanted to show named groups color coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem you have is trying to write a regex that matches ALL the key=value pairs. That's not the way to do it. The correct way is based on a pattern that matches ONLY ONE `key=value`, but is applied by a function that finds all accurances of the pattern. Every languages supplies such a function. Here's the code in Python for example:

```
import re

txt = 'my_app|key1=value1|user_id=testuser|ip_address=10.10.10.10'

pairs = re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^|]+)', txt)
print(pairs)
```

This gives:
    [('key1', 'value1'), ('user_id', 'testuser'), ('ip_address', '10.10.10.10')]

The pattern matches a key consisting of alpha-numeric chars -  (`\w+`) with a value. The value is designated by (`[^|]+`), that is everything but a vertical line, because the value can have non-alpha numeric values, such a dot in the ip address.

Mind the `findall` function. There's a `search` function to catch a pattern once, and there's a `findall` function to catch all the patterns within the text.
I tested it on regex101 and it worked.
I must comment, though, that the specific text pattern you work on doesn't require regex. All high level languages supply a `split` function. You can split by vertical line, and then each slice you get (expcept the first one) you split again by the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with the following code:

```
import regex
s = "my_app|key1=value1|user_id=testuser|ip_address=10.10.10.10"
rx = r"(?<appName>\w+)(?:\|(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>[^|]+))+"

print( [(m.group("appName"), dict(zip(m.captures("key"),m.captures("value")))) for m in regex.finditer(rx, s)] )
# => [('my_app', {'ip_address': '10.10.10.10', 'key1': 'value1', 'user_id': 'testuser'})]
```

See the [Python demo online](https://rextester.com/NXS5280).

The `.captures` property contains all the values captured into a group at all the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe regular expression might be unnecessary, and splitting similar to,

```
data='my_app|key1=value1|user_id=testuser|ip_address=10.10.10.10'

x= data.split('|')
appName = []
for index,item in enumerate(x):
    if index>0:
        element = item.split('=')
        temp = {"key":element[0],"value":element[1]}
        appName.append(temp)
appName = str(x[0] + ',' + str(appName))
print(appName)
```

might return an output similar to the desired output:

```
my_app,[{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}, {'key': 'user_id', 'value': 'testuser'}, {'key': 'ip_address', 'value': '10.10.10.10'}]
```

using `dict`:

```
 temp = {"key":element[0],"value":element[1]}
```

`temp` can be modified to other desired data structure that you like to have.